# Design consideration for pythonic async eventsystem

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, inspect

I have a tiny event async eventsystem like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from uuid import uuid4

class EventSystem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handlers = defaultdict(dict)

    def register_handler(self, event, callback, register_id=None):
        register_id = register_id or uuid4()
        self.handlers[event][register_id] = callback
        return register_id

    def unregister_handler(self, event, register_id):
        del self.handlers[event][register_id]

    def clear_handlers(self, event):
        handler_register_ids = list(self.handlers[event].keys())
        for register_id in handler_register_ids:
            self.unregister_handler(event, register_id)

    async def fire_event(self, event, data):
        handlers = self.handlers[event]
        for register_id, callback in handlers.items():
            await callback(data)
        return len(handlers)
```

Which currently forces handlers to be `async` functions.

I cannot decide what is more pythonic, enforcing this policy, and having an `async2sync` wrapper for sync functions:

```
async def async2sync(func, *args, **kwargs):
     return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or changing `fire_event` to checking the handler type, using `inspect.isawaitable`:

```
    async def fire_event(self, event, data):
        handlers = self.handlers[event]
        for register_id, callback in handlers.items():
            ret = callback(data)
            if inspect.isawaitable(ret):
                await ret
        return len(handlers)
```

I am not worried about long-running or blocking sync functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the wrapper in your first approach wraps sync functions into async, shouldn't it be called `sync2async` rather than `async2sync`?

If long-running or blocking sync functions are not a concern, both approaches are fine. Both have benefits and drabacks. The first approach is a bit more minimalistic and easier to reason about. The second approach is a bit more clever (which can bite you when you least expect), but also much more pleasant to use because you can just write either kind of function for handler and things will "just work". If the user of your API is someone other than yourself, they will probably appreciate it.

TL;DR Either is fine; I'd personally probably go with the second.